# How can I use the intel pin tool to count the instruction executed on linux?

Tags: linux, instructions, intel-pin

everyone, I am a fresh here as well as to linux
i want to use the intel pin tool to help me count the instructions executed in a quick sort program, just a homework, but when i did this as the readme document told me, like
cd source/tools/SimpleExamples
make obj-ia32/opcodemix.so
the system told me
make: *** No rule to make target `obi-ia32/opcodemix.so'.  Stop.
and i also tried obj-intel64,nothing changed.
can anybody tell me what is going on here, i am really confused with this pin stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell exactly what your question is. Format your commands with the code and separate them line by line, so I can know what you executed.

Anyway, if I'm right, you should just type:

```
make
```

(without targets) in under source/tools/ManualExamples, and it should build them all.

Comment: The README claims that you need to give make a target, but as you've pointed out, that is not so!

Comment: You can specify whether to compile for 64 or 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd pintool/source/tools/ManualExamples
```

type command as

```
make inscount0.test
```

this commnad compile and show you the out put file then use following command on same directory

```
../../../pin -t obj-ia32/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls
```

this will make .so file after that see the ouput by using following command

```
cat inscount.out
```